# How can I make my outlet that is controlled by a light switch always be hot?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

[image][photo of wires in light switch[image: ][1]]The light switch the outlet is connected to powers three outlets, another light switch, and two hallway lights. So currently my hallway light switch powers on two lights one at the top of the stairs and one at the bottom of the stairs. There is a room in my basement with three outlets and a light switch that controls the light in that room. The outlets and light switch in the room do not work unless the hallway light switch is turned on.

[image]

[image: photo of the wires inside of the outlet]

Comment: 1) Show us the wiring inside the switch that controls all this. 2) Rewire this outlet to not use the "backstabs" - they're prone to coming loose, causing intermittent failure in the outlet and possibly a fire. Search this site for "backstab" and you'll find all sorts of info about the issue and how to fix it.

Comment: I added photo of wires inside light switch. This is a double switch the bottom switch is the one that controls all of these things

Comment: The outlet pictured is not (directly) attached to the switch pictured. The switch is, apparently, part of a switch loop (power comes into a light fixture somewhere, then only the hot runs to the switch and switched hot continues on - no neutral at the switch). _Plus_ the wiring at the switch appears to be in conduit (individual, blue insulated wires), while the wiring at the outlet is NM-B (a white cable with individual black/white/bare wires inside it). The wiring to this outlet taps off somewhere else.

Comment: Start searching the lights & other outlets looking for the source of the cable that comes into the outlet in question. Make sure you take _labeled_ pictures of _all_ wiring _before_ disconnecting anything to make sure you can put it all back together again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your title says outlet but you mention 3 outlets. Do you want all 3 outlets constantly hot or just one. Are all three outlets the only thing controlled by one switch and the lights are controlled by the other switch.

Comment: If there are only the 3 wires at the dual switch there would need to pull at least a neutral that is assuming metal conduit was used , hard to tell.

Comment: I'm a little troubled by seeing metal conduit at the switch, yet an addition clearly added later that uses Romex.  Usually when conduit is used, it's because it is required by local rules (e.g. Chicagoland). Perhaps this addition was done by an amateur who didn't know that and also didn't know how to tap an unswitched outlet.  Are more outlets switched than you want?  That could be a miswiring of the switch.  Every room needs a light switch that works.

Comment: Do the hallway lights have their own switches, or are they controlled off that same switch?

Comment: There is a light switch in the room with the outlets however it only provides power to the light fixture and it also relies on the light switch in the hallway to be on to work. I’m only interested in making 1 of the 3 outlets always hot.

Comment: Where are you? A set up like that is risky if the wires for lighting and plug sockets are rated for different currents. All I can tell is that you aren't in the UK (where, ideally, you'd have those on separate rings).

Comment: This really needs to be chased down to identify where the power comes into this group of devices, what order they all connect in, why it appears that some is in conduit and some is not, and why one light switch is controlled by another (another issue that should be fixed and shouldn't be difficult to fix if there's conduit). There are likely code violations galore in this work. Strongly consider hiring an electrician to review and fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You ask: How can I make my outlet that is controlled by a light switch always be hot?" Two solutions come to mind, leave the switch on or connect the two wires connected to the switch together.